# How can I have a list selection like the theme accent color picker in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 app, I would like a "depressed state" when the item is held on as in the themes, accent color setting for my lists. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was added in a later release of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/c1715506-9dec-4960-bfdb-699b17982496/#1ae4ee09-8ab3-45bb-baed-c5b5bc27fd0c):

> I think the easiest way would be to go
>   via Expression Blend. Right click on
>   your ListBox (the main control, not
>   its items). Then go to "Edit
>   Additional Templates....(Item
>   Container Style)....Edit Current".
>   Blend will then load a new page for
>   you to modify the styling of the
>   container. In the top left pane (where
>   you can choose project, assets etc...)
>   click on "States". You'll see a list
>   of states.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not worried about the technical - im wondering about how to replicate the experience.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you not creating an application that has a different style whenever an item is selected?

Comment: I want to replicate the animations. I want to know what to set to make the animations be the same.